# Functions being executed at definition? -JS

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

I'm going through the Google maps API guides and noticed that the demo on this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering is using the functions defined inside of initMap() apparently without actually calling them. The only related info I can find is people mistakenly adding a () at the end of a function when defining or passing as a variable, but I don't see that happening here - **How are these functions being executed?**

```
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
  });

  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  // Add some markers to the map.
  // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
  // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
  // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
  });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
      {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code creates new objects, passing along existing ones. For instance when `map` is declared, the code calls `new google.maps.Map(...)`, passing along `document.getElementById('map')`. The constructor of the `Map` object creates the map and displays it inside the element. The variable isn't really needed, except later when the markers are added.

You could in fact remove `var markerCluster =` from the code above and it would still work fine.

If your question is how the Google Maps API knows how to call `initMap`, see Eric's answer.

Comment: Are you saying that setting the vars in the constructor with the passed element finder sets the page up through association / merely setting up the object does the work, and the function doesn't actually call/execute?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying now, the constructor isn't just creating a new object, but doing other work by creating and applying the map - the constructor is the function at work, not the newly created object 'map' and it's being called through 'new'. Correct?

Comment: Yep, that's basically it. You can read up on OO JS to find out more about this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is hidden in the HTML:

```
<script async defer 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

See the `callback` parameter? That tells Google Maps to call a globally-defined function named `initMap` as soon as the library is done loading.

Comment: It's clear how initMap() is called, but I do not understand where markerCluster() is called, for instance.